# Error when creating phoenix form and submitting it

Tags: database, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new to phoenix and elixir.
Trying to create form to submit 1 sentence into database and i am getting an error when click submit form.
Btw. I am following some course and i'm a lot confused.
There are codes 
  Opa_Controller.ex

```
 defmodule Test.OpaController do
   use Test.Web, :controller
     alias Test.Opa

    def new(conn,_params) do
     struct = %Test.Opa{}
     params = %{}
     changeset = Test.Opa.changeset(struct,params)
     render conn, "sex.html", changeset: changeset
   end
   def create(conn,%{"naziv" => naziv}) do

     changeset = Opa.changeset(%Opa{}, naziv)
    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, post} -> IO.inspect(post)
       {:error, changeset} -> IO.inspect(changeset)
   end
   end
 end
```

Test.ex

```
 defmodule Test.Opa do
   use Test.Web, :model

   schema "opala" do
     field :naziv, :string
   end

   def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
     struct
     |> cast(params, [:naziv])
     |> validate_required ([:naziv])
   end
 end
```

Html file

```
 <%= form_for @changeset, opa_path(@conn, :create), fn f -> %>
     <%= text_input f, :naziv, placeholder: "naziv" %>
     <%= submit "Save Topic" %>
 <% end %>
```

Router.ex

```
     get "/", PageController, :index
     get "/opa/new", OpaController, :new
     get "/hello", HelloController, :index
     post "/opa", OpaController, :create
```

In terminal i am getting

```
     [debug] ** (Phoenix.ActionClauseError) could not find a matching      Test.OpaController.create clause
     to process request. This typically happens when there is a
     parameter mismatch but may also happen when any of the other
     action arguments do not match. The request parameters are:

       %{"_csrf_token" => "BDgWfgElRhRdSgoFBTo0BF4+P1YXNgAAtANQOf4Fi+GIlpej+Mt1eg==", "_utf8" => "✓", "opa" => %{"naziv" => "sa"}}
```

In browser: https://pastebin.com/A2Z3466D

Answer (score 0):

The create action is expecting a top-level map key `"naziv"`, seen by the function definition:

```
def create(conn,%{"naziv" => naziv}) do
```

The params being sent to the controller action -- as seen in the error message -- are:

```
%{
  "_csrf_token" => "BDgWfgElRhRdSgoFBTo0BF4+P1YXNgAAtANQOf4Fi+GIlpej+Mt1eg==",
  "_utf8" => "✓",
  "opa" => %{"naziv" => "sa"}
}
```

As we can see, `"naziv"` is nested under the top-level `"opa"` key.

What we actually want to get past that is to change the pattern matching in the create function, so that it expects a top-level `"opa"` key:

```
    def create(conn,%{"opa" => opa_params}) do
      changeset = Opa.changeset(%Opa{}, opa_params)
      case Repo.insert(changeset) do
        {:ok, post} -> IO.inspect(post)
        {:error, changeset} -> IO.inspect(changeset)
      end
    end
```

Comment: For this particular case one might even do `def create(conn,%{"opa" => %{"naziv" => naziv}})`to fail on malformed params sooner.